# Changes are not reflecting in azure app service after deploying via azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, web-deployment

I have a CI/CD pipeline in the Azure DevOps pipeline that deploys the app into the Azure App Service. Both the build and release pipelines are executing without any errors. Before some days, the deployed changes were working fine but now the changes are not reflecting even though the pipeline is executing without any errors.

Release pipeline definition: https://prnt.sc/UE1039_bI6Tz

While analyzing the release pipeline, in the 'Deploy azure app service' task it shows,
`Total changes: 0 (0 added, 0 deleted, 0 updated, 0 parameters changed`

build pipeline debug log file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ReX_rCuqANfvmFrfHb7es-CiU7GxDEPf?usp=share_link

release pipeline debug log file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xrokn_itGWMKqcKRMIRf-OigRhJOHvVp/view?usp=share_link

I checked the artifact created in build pipeline and the changes are there in artifact. But in the release pipeline the changes are not refelected. I checked in the kudu console and the changes are not there also.

When I manually deploy the changes to the app services, they are successfully deployed and the changes are reflected. I don't know what happens behind the scene.

Can anyone please guide me on this? Thanks!

I need the changes to be reflected in the azure app service deployed via the azure DevOps release pipeline.

Comment: First, use powershell or command task to check whether the contents in the zip file has been the latest version. Second, I notice you are using 'slot', so the contents will be deployed to the slot instead of the original website.

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT You mean build artifact zip file right? We already analyzed that manually by downloading that and we see the changes are there in the zip file... And Yes we are using slots. So what is the effect if we deployed in the slot? Won't it reflect on the app websites? But it was working fine with the same configuration before. Could you please tell me some more info about the deployment? Am totally new to the azure app service deployment. Sorry for the noob questions! Thanks for the effort!

Comment: Please check if it's due to task version 4.212 and 4.213, and works fine on version 4.214.

Checkout -[Fix for Cosmetic API calls- microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks@b82a8e6 GitHub][1] | causes no KUDU deployment history for Web Deploy.

Also, ["AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4" to be published? · microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks · GitHub][2]


  [1]: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/commit/b82a8e69eb862d1a9d291af70da2e62ee69270df#diff-b8eb531ecea5edc3262148d3b26353f51ee992b6dc48e7a7820cf59411468e54
  [2]: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/17497